# Get upcoming birthdays mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to display the upcoming birthdays.
The birthdays are stored by a timestamp with mysql.

I found in a earlier question with the follow code:

```
 select *
from t
order by (case when month(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth))) = month(now()) and
                day(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth))) > day(now()) or
                month(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth))) > month(now())
           then 1 else 0
      end) desc,
     month(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth))),
     day(date(from_unixtimestamp(user_birth)))
 limit 6
```

But this doesn't work for the function from_unixtimestamp() doesn't exist on my server.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the function is [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).